# Android 13 - Permission to access files created on PC and copied to download folder on tablet

Tags: android

Each week I manually create a text file on a PC listing the details of yachts competing in the weekend's racing. The file is copied to a folder on the Android tablet hoping my Race Management App can read the competitor file. It can't.

Android 13 (actually 11) has introduced additional file protections. These changes include removing the simple permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE so the following code fails to even list the PC created file

```
private fun listDirectories() {
    val internalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    internalStorage.listFiles()?.forEach { file ->
        if (file.isDirectory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Directory : ${file.name}")
            listFilesInDirectory(file.path)
        }
    }
}

private fun listFilesInDirectory(directory: String) {
    val dir = File(directory)
    val files = dir.listFiles() // Get all files in the directory
    if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No Files in directory $directory")
    } else {
        files.forEach { file ->
        Log.d(TAG,"Found file ${file.name}") }
    }
}
```

The above code only lists files created by the App itself. It will not list the files created by the PC

The following code proves a file exists on the tablet and is readable. It asks the user to select a file which is then viewed

```
private fun letUserChooseFile() {
    // let the user select the file
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    openFileLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

The problem is I can't work out how to modify the above to intercept the selection rather than just view it.

I am reluctant to use the new permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE because I hope to eventually list the Race Management App on the Play Store and since is it not a file management app its inclusion would probably result in Google blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on requests user permission for the App to access the required folder

```
private fun requestFolderPermission() {
    val externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val folder = File(externalStorageDir, "RaceManagement/Entrants")
    val storageManager = application.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val intent =  storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
    val targetDirectory = "Android%2F$folder" // user will be prompted for permission to access this directory
    val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI") as Uri
    else
        intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Uri::class.java) as Uri
    val uriString = uri.toString().replace("/root/", "/document/") + "%3A$targetDirectory"
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Uri.parse(uriString))
    val activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            result.data?.data?.let { directoryUri ->
                // make the permission persistent using takePersistableUriPermission()
                val modeFlags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(directoryUri, modeFlags)
                listFiles(directoryUri)
                // save the persistent permission (see comment)
            }
        }
    }
    activityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

No file permissions are included in the Manifest!

Asking the user for the required permission is only required the first time the app is run. The returned uri is simply saved to sharedPreferences()

```
val editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
editor.putString(KEY_NAME, directoryUri.toString())
editor.apply()
```

Shared preferences is checked and either the permission is requested or the app uses the saved value

```
val preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
val directoryUri = preferences.getString(KEY_NAME, null)
if (directoryUri == null) {
    requestFolderPermission()
} else {
    listFiles(Uri.parse(directoryUri))
}
```

While App dependent for completeness here is a simple listFiles() function

```
private fun listFiles(directoryUri: Uri) {
    val folder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, directoryUri)!!
    if (folder.isDirectory) {
        folder.listFiles().forEach { file ->
            file.name.let {
                file.name?.let { // do something with the files
                    filename -> Log.d(TAG, filename) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone